# How to add mysql-python image path to crontab

Tags: python, mysql, macos, cron, mysql-python

Crontab always try to load mysql-python image from my home directory, while the library image is actually in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python`... How can I point crontab to the right place? Without reinstall mysql-python as a static library?

I work on MAC OS 10.7. 
Thanks.

Comment: can you share some insight on your crontab-called scripts?

Comment: I cannot `import mysql-python` right at the beginning. The script runs well from command line. Currently, i have to run it continuously, and if my internet disconnects, it will stop.

Comment: have you properly setup you environment for cron? remember it runs separately from your configs

Comment: seems like an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339788/cannot-import-mysql-python-in-crontab-mac-os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `env` at your command-line and copy its output. Add that to the top of your crontab, as that will set the environment for the cron to run - this should do the trick. You can then remove unwanted environment variables at your own leisure.

Reference for Mac OS X:

**crontab file**

When you add cron jobs (using conrtab -e), they are neither run under your Mac OS X login nor under a tcsh shell, so you can also set envrionment variables in your crontab which will get used when executing cron actions.

```
PERL5LIB=/Library/Perl:/Users/yourusername/perl
LC_ALL=C

12 1 * * * perl dosomething.pl
```

Source: [Peter's Mac OS X Notes](http://www.peter.com.au/macosx/index.html#environment).

Notice that the environment setting on cron does *NOT* require you to add the `export` commands. Drop them at the top of the cron file and that will do it.